# React Native: dispatch events in a bridge module in a serial queue

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, react-native

I have a method in ObjC (custom bridge module) that runs dispatches an event (with some data) to React Native, like so:

```
[self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"onMessage" body:message];
```

There will lots of such `message`s coming in sequence from JS (browser thread, I suppose) which I want to execute separately in order to not block the shadow queue (where UI layout happens). I was thinking of executing them in a serial queue like so:

```
dispatch_async(my_unique_serial_queue, ^{

  [self.bridge.eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName:@"onMessage" body:message];

});
```

Does the bridge eventDispatcher method already take care of this queueing for me? If so, I don't need to process in `my_unique_serial_queue`, right?